# remove border of a gtk.button

Tags: python, gtk

I want to remove the border of the gtk.button, but i Don't know how to do it.

I tried with :

```
button = gtk.Button()
button.set_style("inner-border",0)
```

but i have an error :  the property doesn't exist.
I tried too to create a new gtk.Style and use it for the button, but same error.

Anyone has an idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Set the button's `relief` property:

```
button.props.relief = gtk.RELIEF_NONE
```

Full test program:

```
import gtk

window = gtk.Window ()
box    = gtk.VButtonBox ()

for k in range (10):
    button = gtk.Button ('button %d' % k)
    if k % 2 == 0:
        button.props.relief = gtk.RELIEF_NONE

    box.add (button)

window.add (box)
window.show_all ()

gtk.main ()
```

If this doesn't work for you, then your GTK+ theme doesn't support `RELIEF_NONE`.

Answer (score 1):

```
label_box = Gtk::HBox.new(false, 0) 
label = Gtk::Label.new('Page1') 
label_box.pack_start(label, false, false, 0) 

btn = Gtk::Button.new 
btn.relief = Gtk::RELIEF_NONE 
btn.focus_on_click = false 
style = btn.modifier_style 
style.xthickness = 0 
style.ythickness = 0 
btn.modify_style(style) 
btn.set_tooltip_text("Close page1") 
wim,him = Gtk::IconSize.lookup(Gtk::IconSize::MENU) 
btn.set_size_request(wim+2,him+2) 
btn.signal_connect('clicked') do 
  $notebook.remove_page($notebook.children.index(treeview)) 
  store.clear 
  label_box.destroy 
  treeview.destroy 
end 

image = Gtk::Image.new(Gtk::Stock::CLOSE, Gtk::IconSize::MENU) 
btn.add(image) 

align = Gtk::Alignment.new(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0) 
align.add(btn) 
label_box.pack_start(align, false, false, 0) 

label_box.spacing = 3 
label_box.show_all 

page = $notebook.append_page(treeview, label_box) 
treeview.show_all 
$notebook.page = $notebook.n_pages-1
```

Answer (score 1):

Short version:

```
import gtk
window = gtk.Dialog()
button = gtk.Button('Click Me')
button.props.relief = gtk.RELIEF_NONE
window.vbox.pack_start(button)
window.show_all()
window.run()
```