# How to remove frame (or border?) form a GtkScrolledWindow

Tags: c#, gtk, gtk#

How I can remove the frame (or the border if it is...) of a GtkScrolledWindow (gtk#)?
Use of `window.ShadowType = ShadowType.None;` don't work, `window.BorderWidth=0;` don't work...

Thanks for help!

Comment: You might be able to do this by setting a style property - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846390/remove-border-of-a-gtk-button

Answer (score 3):

Set the `FormBorderStyle` property of your `Form` to None.