# Remove GtkScrolledWindow frame border in C

Tags: c, gtk, scrolledwindow

I read about the removing of border from this GTK widget (you can see it in this image http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/scrolledwindow.png) in Python or C#

- [remove border of a gtk.button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846390/remove-border-of-a-gtk-button)
- [How to remove frame (or border?) form a GtkScrolledWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927416/how-to-remove-frame-or-border-form-a-gtkscrolledwindow)

How to do that if I'm working in ANSI C? How can I set the "famous" border style property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured out by myself. My scrollable window is `scrollable_component`, the trick is to get its child, that's the viewport, and set its shadow property.

```
gtk_viewport_set_shadow_type(GTK_VIEWPORT(gtk_bin_get_child(scrollable_component)), GTK_SHADOW_NONE);
```